# C# LINQ get objects with field value that do not match a string array blacklist

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public class MyObject {
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public MyObject(string name) {
    Name = name;
  }  
}

// caller method somewhere
public void myMethod() {
  List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("Jim"));
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("David"));
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("Richard"));
  myObjects.Add(new MyObject("Steve"));

  string[] namesToExclude = new string[] { "Jim", "Steve" };
  List<string> strings = myObjects.Select(m => m.Name).Except(namesToExclude).ToList();
  // replace the above line to result in List<MyObject> with 2 items (David, Richard)
}
```

I'd like to get this last line working so I can get back the list as a `List<MyObject>` rather than as a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var objects = 
      myObjects.Where(m => !namesToExclude.Contains(m.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: I may have been unclear here. I think you've missed my point.  I do NOT want a result of a list of strings.  I want to get the list of objects back.  The code above already works.

Comment: Not the most efficient but the shortest.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Except` and `join` the result to the original list

```
var allowedObjNames = myObjects.Select(o => o.Name).Except(namesToExclude);
var allowedObject = from o in myObjects join a in allowedObjNames 
                    on o.Name equals a
                    select o;
var allowedObjList = allowedObject.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this also insightful answer.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

this may be slightly wrong as I'm used to using VB.NET more, but something like...

```
(from m in myObjects where !namesToExclude.Contains(m.Name)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var objs = myObjects.Where(m => !namesToExclude.Contains(m.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace last line with -

```
List<MyObject> objects = myObjects.Where(o =>
                           !namesToExclude.Contains(o.Name)).ToList();
```